# SSL on appspot.com subdomain of non-default version

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, https

I want to use SSL on the non-default version of my GAE app. For the normal https://my-app.appspot.com I know I don't have to do a thing. However I have another version, which would be under https://v2.my-app.appspot.com and there SSL doesn't work. It gives following error in the browser:

> Your connection is not private
>
> Attackers might be trying to steal your
> information from dev.replimeapp.appspot.com (for example, passwords,
> messages, or credit cards). NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use following address instead: https://v2-dot-my-app.appspot.com/

> Google does not issue SSL certificates for double-wildcard domains hosted at appspot.com. Therefore with HTTPS you must use the string "-dot-" instead of "." to separate subdomains, as shown in the examples below. You can use a simple "." with your own custom domain or with HTTP addresses.

From there: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml#Secure_URLs

Comment: page not found for v2 link

Comment: That's an example of a potential URL, as it was mentioned originally